# Adding fields to content type edit form (not to the node itself)

Tags: 8

In Drupal 8, how do you add fields to the content type edit form, i.e. where you define the content type?  I know how to add fields to the content type that wind up on the node edit form, but I'm looking to add a field to the content type itself.  Essentially, what I'm trying to do is add some data to content types that would allow me to group them together.  To do this, I need to add some additional metadata to the content type beyond name and description.

Comment: What's the end goal with grouping the content types?

Comment: Adding some data to content types would be a use case for [ThirdPartySettings](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21Entity%21ThirdPartySettingsInterface.php/interface/ThirdPartySettingsInterface/9.0.x). I've found this great blog post as example https://kevinquillen.com/using-thirdpartysettings-api-drupal

Comment: @4k4, this is exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickKenny, I need to collect content of different types together and will use the "type" of content type to do so.  Ultimately, I'll create views handler surface the grouping and filter nodes on the type of content type they are.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to create custom entities.

Try reading [Creating a content entity type in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/creating-a-content-entity-type-in-drupal-8) and maybe this module can help: [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity)